# Как получить id пользователя, которого кикнули (исключили) из беседы?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мой вопрос заключается в том: как узнать id пользователя, которого кикнули (исключили) из беседы ВКонтакте? Я не знаю как, не могли бы вы мне подсказать?

Comment: Как понять "кикнули"? Куда и откуда?

Comment: Исключили из беседы ВКонтакте.

Comment: Перейти по ссылке на пользователя, которого кикнули?

Comment: Странно что вопрос закрыт ведь все понятно написано, учитывая какие теги у вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод **[messages.getHistory](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory)**, который возвращает историю сообщений для указанного диалога. В каждом из них есть набор определенных полей, в том числе

- было ли сообщение входящим или исходящим
- action — которое говорит, кикнули юзера или пригласили и т.д. (https://vk.com/dev/objects/message)
- **action_mid** — идентификатор пользователя (если > 0) или email (если < 0), которого пригласили или исключили (для служебных сообщений с `action = chat_invite_user` или `chat_kick_user`).

Вот и смотрим на `action` и `action_mid`. Пример:

```
{
    "id": 2125,
    "body": "",
    "user_id": 1,
    "from_id": 1,
    "date": 1447685428,
    "read_state": 1,
    "out": 1,
    "random_id": 0,
    "action": "chat_kick_user", // <!-- искомое поле №1
    "action_mid": 666,          // <!-- искомое поле №2
    "chat_id": 1
}
```